# select all elements in the form except parent div contains display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select elements in form except parent div contains display:none

```
$('*[data-val-required="required"]')
```

here i am able select all elements along with hidden elements in parent div like

```
<div class="form-group" style=" display: none; " >
<div  class="col-sm-3 control-label">
    lable
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<select class="form-control"  data-val-required="This field is required" >
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
```

how exclude these elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target `.form-group` and use the [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo selector:

```
$('.form-group:visible *[data-val-required="required"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Can use the `:hidden` selector combined with `not()` to exclude them

```
$('*[data-val-required="required"]').not(':hidden')
```

When a parent is hidden , so are it's descendants

Reference [:hidden selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to do this is use the class on the parent like this :

`$('.form-group:visible *[data-val-required="required"]')`

but be carreful the `:visible` pseudo selector return true for `visibility:hidden` and `opacity:0`

https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If you only have specific element you do not want to select. Then use the not() selector from jQuery.

fx. $('*[data-val-required="required"]').not('.control-label')

see documentation: http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Would have commented, and asked for further info, since I didn't completely get what was needed. But I agree - your markup makes more sense - I only provided an example based on what I could derive from the question.